# a special Person class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am a newbie in C++ as I am learning it at college, and I have a problem. I have a project to do that should be fairly easy to do, but I seem to encounter some difficulties. I must implement a Person class, with exactly 3 arguments: name, firstnames (this is my BIG problem because there can be several names put in an array of char*, so it will be a char**) and age. My teacher gave me a testPerson.cc file in which it uses my Person class to create several types of Persons. My problem is when I create the constructor(s), because I must manage several cases: for example if a person has only one first name, for example:

```
  const Personne lea ("Tralala", "Lea", 45);
```

or a person has several firstnames:

```
  const char* prenoms1[] = {"Marcel", "Firmin", "Gaston", 0};
  const Personne marcel ("Meharcele",  prenoms1, 78);
```

I know for sure that I must have exactly 3 attributes: name(char*), firstname(char**), age(int).

Here is a snippet from the file that the teacher gave me(which I must respect when creating my Person class):

```
int main () {
  cout << "We create the next persons:\n";

  // version of constructor with several names:
  const char* prenoms1[] = {"Marcel", "Firmin", "Gaston", 0};
  const Personne marcel ("Meharcele",  prenoms1, 78);

  // version of constructor with only one name:
  const Personne lea ("Tralala", "Lea", 45);
```

As you can see, I need several constructors for cases with only 1 fname, or several fnames
And here is my class:

```
#include "personne.h"

Personne::Personne(const char* name, const char** fnames, int a) {
    nom = name;
    prenom = fnames;
    age = a;

}
Personne::Personne(const char* name, const char* fname, int a) {
    nom = name;
    prenom = fname; //here I have a problem, since the attribute prenom is of type char**
    age = a;

}

void Personne::setAge(int& a) {
  age = a;
}

void Personne::setNom(const char* name) {
  nom = name;
}

void Personne::setPrenoms(const char** fnames) {

}

int Personne::getAge() const {
  return age;
}

char* Personne::getNom() const {
  return nom;
}

char** Personne::getPrenoms() const {
  return prenom;
}
```

I spent hours and hours thinking about a solution, I googled a lot(so I did my homework), it's just that I do not know how to implement the right solution.

Comment: If you can use STL this will be made much easier with `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 7):

Some considerations:

- a single first name can be seen as an array of one element so you can still use an array to internally store the list of first names, and let it be of size 1 when there is only one.
- in your constructor you are assigning pointers which are allocated on stack in the caller of your constructor, while this doesn't create problems in your specific snipped, it isn't the right way to do it: you should create your own copy of each value of the person so that they don't get lost once the parameters are lost and manage their destruction in the `Personne` destructor `~Personne()`
- I don't know if you are allowed to use STL library, in that case consider using [`string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to store names and [`vector<string>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) list of names, they will do most of the dirty work for you

Comment: +1 for recommending using string and vector<string>. Much of C++'s bad reputation comes from forcing/encouraging use of raw arrays and pointers on beginners where use of string, vector, etc would help them think more about problem solving.